# Sharepoint 2013 extremely slow

Tags: 2013, performance, virtual-machine

We have an new sharepoint 2013 site, Server Virtual and standalone , it has 12 gb ram. 
This sharepoint user interface extremely slow.

In Developer Dashboard we see each aspx page requests waiting about 6-7 second.

[image: Aspx request waiting]

[image: sql execute details in aspx request]

Have any idea ?

Comment: what's your full system specifications and what have you installed on it so far.

Comment: on developer dashboard tumbnail.aspx waiting about 7000 ms, you can see call stack below; ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5rtvN.jpg) ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CtltZ.jpg) SqlCommand: 'proc_FetchDocForHttpGet' CommandType: StoredProcedure CommandTimeout: 0 Parameter: '@RETURN_VALUE' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: ReturnValue Value: '' Parameter: '@DocSiteId' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '1e581f6c-2a2d-4df3-bb27-6425f6ae152f' Parameter: '@DocDirName' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'DivanHotel/PR2' P

Comment: Obviously your SQL communication is slow, There might very well be some bad configuration in SQL Server. How much memory is your SQL server instance using (in Task Manager)? And how much CPU?

Comment: using only 450 mb

Comment: sory you asked cpu: cpu using only between 0-2

Comment: I have the exact same experience, about 6 seconds to load any aspx page. Every time, even reload takes the same time. All other content seems fast enought.
The server(web + app) uses ony 25% of the 12GB RAM and the CPU (2 cores) never gets above 40%.
Search is disabled/stopped. Any ideas? Did you get this performance issue solved? Regards //
Thomas Balkeståhl - Senior Executive Consultant – MVP

Comment: Sefer, did you try turning off Distributed Cache?  It solved the problem for Thomas.

Answer (score 24):

My problem solved!

Have a follow [this link](http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/05/15/sharepoint-2013-page-loads-takes-a-very-long-time/).

**Turn off distributed cache:**

[image]

**Site loading time with it off:**

[image]

**site loading time with it on:**

[image]

> !!! From 6.10 seconds down to 79
>   ms

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. And please don't add a sig. Oh, and don't plug your own blog with out adding a disclaimer - please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.

Comment: This worked for me too. What about the prod environment though is this distributed cache service broken?

Comment: This was the perfect solution, could you please update the answer on the actual question as well as the link?

Comment: I turned mine off, still terribly slow on new laptop VM with 16GB RAM and SSD.

Comment: Turning off Distributed Cache is NOT a fix. You will find some functionality will no longer be available without it, but likely in an unnoticed manner. Turning this off only means that you do not have enough memory assigned to the virtual machine. In fact a single-node SP2013 farm is almost completely a waste of time. I highly recommend at the very least adding an additional server to the farm to just run Distributed Cache, but ultimately two more, to split off Service Applications like Search, too.

Comment: If you think this is an answer, please do not post a follow up question asking why the Social Features are broken. Turning off DC will kill all SharePoint Social features on the "Network" page. This is not an answer for poor performance.

Comment: Thanks for you complete answer. I just have a question, where are the windows that you have captured in the question? I mean is it the checking windows or it's in Server system? I'm asking since I'm not the administrator so probably I'm not familiar with the server itself.

Comment: If this isn't the solution, how do you fix distributed cache?

Answer (score 9):

For driving SP 2013 with only 12 GB of RAM I recommend that you [stop](http://www.gknzcfc.net/subsite/continuous-crawl-on-sharepoint-2013.html) the search from doing continous crawls, and to stop any services that you do not plan to use. Otherwise you will ned a bit more memory.

The search continous crawl uses a massive amount of system resources, so in a low performance environment, it should be turned of if it is not extremely necessary for your purposes.

Also make sure that the virtual machine is allowed to use more than one processor core in your VM environment settings (This got me once in Hyper-V)

Comment: Most of sharepoint services (like search service) is already stopped and in performance monitor ram usage is only 5-6 gb. Let's check vm envrionment

Answer (score 6):

For me, reprovisioning the distributed cache service resolved the performance issue:

```
$serviceInstance. = Get-SPServiceInstance | Where { $_.TypeName -like "Distributed Cache"}
$serviceInstance.Unprovision()
$serviceInstance.Provision()
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still struggling with this the answer is [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj219613(office.15).aspx).

I also had very slow performance, I increased the memory allocated to the Distributed Cache from the default of 410MB to 7168MB and now my site is behaving as it should do.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because your machine doesn't have sufficient memory. SharePoint performance mostly depends on Hard disk and memory however SP 2013 is a memory beast, I don't think 12gb is enough if it's a single development server, check this article out,

[Why SharePoint 2013 requires so much memory?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/cc0a8228-ce87-4db6-824e-50b709fb48ee/)

I installed SharePoint 2013 on a single box along with 6gb and all I was able to do is to create a single site collection and since then it stopped working.

**Edit**

Since the problem is only when you try to access SharePoint in browser, you should enable Developer Dash board and check what factor is taking most time while page loads.

[Developer Dashboard in SharePoint 2013](http://sps2013.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

Enable it using PowerShell,

```
$content = ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService)
$appsetting =$content.DeveloperDashboardSettings
$appsetting.DisplayLevel = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::On
$appsetting.Update()
```

Comment: In performance monitor ram usage is only 5-6 gb. There are not content on db, only empty sharepoint template.

Comment: @SeferKILIÇ you need to enable DD to monitor then

Comment: I see in DD , all aspx request waiting about 6000 ms,

Comment: On sql tab i saw sql request/response details and I think there is a sql server problem here .

proc_FetchDocForHttpGet 3.525 ms
DECLARE @DocPare 2.690 ms
proc_GetTpWebMetaDataAndListMetaData 2.388 ms
proc_GetWebMetainfo 1.747 ms

Comment: I got this problem with a fresh install of SharePoint 2013 on a single VM, using a backend SQL cluster. The SP server has 8 GB RAM and 8 cores available to it. It runs pretty lean using only 40% of the memory, so far. Still, I was looking at 6 second load times on the Home.aspx page. EVERY time. So I tried stopping the Distributed Cache service, and speed was back up... It's NOT a resource-problem...

Answer (score 1):

For the record, i will add a fast resume of (mostly) all the tips to fine tune SharePoint 2013 for use in a low resource machine (i.e. developer machine or testing machine).  Its not a how-to answer but it could leads to solve some problem

1. Installing the root certificate, disable the clr check or send clr.microsoft.com to the 127.0.0.1. It speed ups the "awake" of the websites. Sometimes considerably. Its also a must have trick for SharePoint 2010.
2. Configure Noderunner to use less memory. Noderunner is configure to use so much memory and it spans over 4 process, each one consuming usually between 300mb-600mb (in total 600x4 = 1.4gb), each one consuming a lot of memory. It could be disable to 256mb or even 128mb.
3. Disable distributed cache.
4. Configure the search service. By default, its configure to about to collect information every minute and its overkill for most system (even for a 24gb machine).   While its possible to disable it but i suggest to configure it correctly to run every hour or every day.
5. Timer Service. If you are updating then, disabling it could speed up the process.
6. Disable the service that you don't want to use.
7. A proper configuration of SharePoint involves a farm of several machines. Specially the database should be installed in a different machine.   However, a dev/testing machine usually includes domain + sql server + sharepoint in the same box.
8. Disable Health and Usage Service.
9. Update SharePoint 2013.  Don't forget to also update the database.
10. Lastly : SharePoint 2010 is way more resource friendly. *wink* *wink* ;-)

Optionally:

11. Configure Sql Server to use another partition/disk. Also you can configure sql server to limit the memory used (usually its configured to use over 2 trillions of bytes).
12. In some cases, Sharepoint 2013 Online is quite inexpensive. Its not blazing fast but its usable.  It costs about $8 per user per month.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem on our farm - same exact issue - 6 second delay for EVERY PAGE.  Distributed Cache is very buggy in some versions and may need patching (we are now on CU4, planning for CU5) as well as TLC from Microsoft Premier support.

Comment: And did CU4 solve the problem at hand?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any solutions installed in your farm? if yes, then please retract all of them and then check the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to tune up the latency, I may recommend couple things.

- Since SQL 2008, SQL supports 64 KB formatted partitions. If you may keep the database in a partition which is formatted as 64 KB, that will increase SharePoint 2013 performance directly.
- On the hand, as default SQL databases increases size by 2 MB each time when needed. You can fix this number for certain amount, database will stop to increase the database size time to time to grow.

With only these two things there is a chance you may increase your SharePoint experience up to %30.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old post but in case someone is still struggling with SP2013 performance in a virtualised environment: turning off dynamic memory allocation to the VMs had a dramatic effect:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saponsqlserver/2013/08/31/virtualization-overcommitting-memory-and-how-to-detect-it-within-the-vm/

http://blog.luxem.org/2013/05/driver-locked-memory-on-hyper-v-guests.html

Answer (score 0):

Thought to post this in case it helps someone. I also struggled with this problem and nothing seem to work. The fastest my page loaded was 9:40s. I disabled distributed cache, re-provisioned, troubleshot search etc but the issue persisted... until I found this:

https://communities.vmware.com/thread/524842?start=0&tstart=0
https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2129176

I was on VMware and Windows 2012R2 like in the  as well.

You can test the performance in your environment but in mine, having WireShark/WinPcap produced faster response time than setting "netsh int tcp set global rsc=disabled"

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue don't mess with Distributed Cache follow the links that Julio left below.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saponsqlserver/2013/08/31/virtualization-overcommitting-memory-and-how-to-detect-it-within-the-vm/

http://blog.luxem.org/2013/05/driver-locked-memory-on-hyper-v-guests.html

Or just run this commands as administrator on your SQL and all App/Web Servers

netsh int tcp set global rsc=disabled

you can verify that it has been disabled via this command

netsh int tcp show global

My response times went from 30000ms on a page that has a bunch of filters webparts down to 311ms.  Other simpler pages are running even faster!!  Thanks Julio!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SharePoint Publishing site and you check the event viewer every once in a while you might see the following warning in there:

Object Cache: The super user account utilized by the cache is not configured.

Below article explains nicely  and I resolved my performance issue.

[here is the article](http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/10/06/resolving-the-super-user-account-utilized-by-the-cache-is.aspx)